# Unable to retrieve data from parent form in InlineCreate operation in backpack for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I implement the InlineCreate Operation in Backpack for Laravel and works fine, but  my field depend of other field and I can't to get the parent field information in the modal or in the setup operation.

**Field Definition**

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'cliente_contacto',
    'type' => "relationship",
    'ajax' => true,
    //'inline_create' => true,
    'inline_create' => [ // specify the entity in singular
        'entity' => 'cliente_contacto', // the entity in singular
        // OPTIONALS
        'force_select' => true, // should the inline-created entry be immediately selected?
        'modal_class' => 'modal-dialog modal-lg', // use modal-sm, modal-lg to change width
        'modal_route' => route('cliente-contacto-inline-create'), // InlineCreate::getInlineCreateModal()
        'create_route' => route('cliente-contacto-inline-create-save'), // InlineCreate::storeInlineCreate()
        'include_main_form_fields' => ['proyecto'] // pass certain fields from the main form to the modal
    ],
    // 'data_source' => backpack_url('presupuesto/fetch/cliente-contacto'),
    // 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione un elemento',
    'minimum_input_length' => 0,
    'dependencies' => ['cliente'], // when a dependency changes, this select2 is reset to null
    //'method'                    => 'POST', // optional - HTTP method to use for the AJAX call (GET, POST)
    //'include_all_form_fields' => true, //sends the other form fields along with the request so it can be filtered.
    'tab' => 'Datos Principales',
    'wrapper' => [
        'class' => 'col-md-3'
    ]
]);
```

**ClienteContactoCrudController**

```
protected function setupInlineCreateOperation()
{
   $parent_loaded_fields = request()->get('parent_loaded_fields');
}
```

But I can't get that fields.
The documentation:
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-inline-create#how-to-use-1

```
'include_main_form_fields' => ['field1', 'field2'], // pass certain fields from the main form to the modal
```

Don't said how get that values.

I found this: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2925#issuecomment-644060749

I can get:

```
'entity' => request()->get('entity'),
'modalClass' => request()->get('modal_class'),
```

But

```
'parentLoadedFields' => request()->get('parent_loaded_fields')
```

Don't work

How can I get de parent field values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should get them with `request('main_form_fields')`.

I've just submitted a PR to the docs to reference that: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/docs/pull/341

Cheers

Comment: Thanks very much, that work for me. 
I only want to add something:
When I load the form in the modal first time, I get only the value definited in

`'include_main_form_fields' => ['proyecto'] // pass certain fields from the main form to the modal` 

But if I close the modal and open It again, I get all the values of the form (_token, _method, _http_referrer , _current_tab , _save_action, and all my parent form fields)

This is possibly a minor detail, But I think that they should continue to show only the defined value, like the first time.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was unware of that issue. I will have a better look tomorrow. Cheers

Comment: Just to let you know that I found the issue and already submitted the PR to fix it, it should be available in the next release, probably next monday!